# How to remove element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div which contains:

```
<div id="div1">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Span1</span>
        <span class="input-group-addon">Span2</span>
        <span class="input-group-addon">Span3</span>
        <span class="input-group-addon npsButton"><a target='_blank' href='nps.html'>Link</a></span>

</div>
```

I tried to remove the last span `.npsButton` by using: `$("#div1").remove("span.npsButton");` but it's not working. When I check by the console `$("#div1span.npsButton")`, it returned []. Can anyone show me how can I remove this span

Comment: Please read [the documentation for `remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use descendant selector

```
$('#div1 .npsButton').remove()
//      ^           Note the space here
```

`$("#div1span.npsButton")` will select the element having ID as `div1span` and class `npsButton`. As there is no element that satisfies this selector, it'll return empty array.

---

To remove **all** elements in DOM having that class,

```
$('.npsButton').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$("span.npsButton").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside selecting using `class` or `id` there are few other ways you can select the last child

1. [:last-child Selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)
2. [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)
3. [:nth-last-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/)

In the following snippet I am using `:last-child` which will select all element that is last child of the parent

```
$( "div#div1 span:last-child" ).remove()
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6sguL84z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$( "#div1 span" ).last().hide();
```